# Server cannot connect to pgbouncer (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, port, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I am trying to set up connectional pooling using pgbouncer 1.7.2 for PostgreSQL 9.6 on Windows 10.

Trying to connect to pgbouncer in the cmd

```
    psql -p 6432 -h 127.0.0.1 postgres pgbouncer
```

gives the error:

```
    psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly Server terminated abnormally before or while processing
```

The port 6432 is listening and looking in the pg_log there are no errors.

Here is my pgbouncer.ini config file:

```
    [databases]

    mydb = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb

    [pgbouncer]

    logfile = pgbouncer.log
    pidfile = pgbouncer.pid

    listen_addr = *
    listen_port = 6432

    auth_type = md5
    auth_file = C:/Program Files/pgbouncer-1.7.2-win32/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt

    admin_users = postgres, lisam

    stats_users = stats, root
```

Where users.txt contains
 "postgres" "some_password"

In the pgbouncer guide it says:

*Since PostgreSQL 9.0, the text files are not used anymore. Thus the auth file needs to be generated. See ./etc/mkauth.py for sample script to generate auth file from pg_shadow table.
PostgreSQL MD5-hidden password format:
"md5" + md5(password + username)*

Does anyone know how to manually generate the auth file?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Lisa

Comment: you can `select 'md5'||md5('password'||'username')` to get the md5 value

Answer (score 4):

you can use postgres md5 function, eg:

```
postgres=# select usename,concat('md5',md5('postregs user password'||usename)) from pg_user where usename='postgres';
 usename  |               concat
----------+-------------------------------------
 postgres | md584f1938f5f80a2f6ba95cea7875ad602
(1 row)
```

that would mean you shoud add

```
"postgres" "md584f1938f5f80a2f6ba95cea7875ad602"
```

to you `C:/Program Files/pgbouncer-1.7.2-win32/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your help!